# Select all children except one with the same tag as the parent using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an XML file which looks something like this:

```
<employee emp="1" dept="55">
        <name>Peter</name>
        <job>Director</job>
        <employee emp="12" dept="26">
                <name>John</name>
                <job>Animator</job>
                <employee emp="123" dept="27">
                        <name>James</name>
                        <job>Assistant</job>
                </employee>
        </employee>
</employee>
```

The structure of the XML represents the structure of the company and I need to select the head of the company (Director), which means selecting the root element `employee` but without any `employee` children.

I tried things like `/employee/*[not(child::employee)]`, but it always returns this:

```
        <name>Peter</name>
        <job>Director</job>
```

instead of what I wanted:

```
<employee emp="1" dept="55">
        <name>Peter</name>
        <job>Director</job>
</employee>
```

How can I change my expression to match the desired output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot transform xml with xpath. What you are looking for is transformation after selection. You could use xslt.

Comment: Or you can try xquery.